# drupal 8.2 to 8.5 update error

Tags: 8

I am getting the following error.

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to
>   Drupal\page_manager\Routing\VariantRouteFilter::__construct() must be
>   an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack, none
>   given, called in
>   /home/ranjith/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php
>   on line 266 and defined in
>   Drupal\page_manager\Routing\VariantRouteFilter->__construct() (line 64
>   of
>   sites/all/modules/contrib/page_manager/src/Routing/VariantRouteFilter.php).

What does it mean? How can I fix that error?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Drupal Answers. We’d love to help you. To **improve your chances** of getting an answer, please follow these rules: [How do I ask a good question?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: The question is actually fairly clear and the answer too: You need to update the page_manager module to the latest version (and other contrib modules possibly too)

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the result of the Drupal service container failing to create a service because its cached definition doesn't match the class anymore: An extra constructor argument was added (in [this change](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/page_manager/commit/?h=8.x-4.x&id=292cddfeca17bea8b95fbcad2ba09b534a913d03)), and Drupal is not passing that argument.

[This is a typical error that can happen after updating modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2918906). Make sure to completely empty your cache manually. You might be able to do this using `drupal cr all` or `drush cr` or by visiting the admin backend, but not if the service is already loaded during bootstrap. In that case, try to empty the `cache_container` database table directly.